# How to use heredoc in a wget command in a shell script once the inserted text is not the last argument?

Tags: shell-script, wget, json, here-document

My problem: when testing an application I use wget to send a JSON to my local Tomcat.

Summing up the command:

```
wget --header='...' --post-data='LONG_JSON' -q0 URL
```

Expanding the command:

```
wget --header='Content-Type:application/json' --post-data='{"foocao": 0, "foorio": { "foo": "foofoofoo", "foofooe": "foofoo", "foon": "fooe", "fool": "foo.com", "fooa": "foofoo" }, "fooade": { "foofoofoo": "foofoo-foo-foo-foo-foofoofoo", "foo": "fooTE", "fool": "baa.com", "foofoo": "foo9-foo", "fooao": "foofoo", "fooor": "foofoo", "foofoo": "foofooia", "foofooo": "fooo", "foos": "✓ foofooade e foofooe;✓ foofooa, foofooação fooal e Polífoo e foofoo foonil;✓ foofoo e foor;✓ foofoofoo, foofoo e fooa;✓ foofooção e foofooe de fooessão;✓ Saúde;✓ fooura;✓ fooação;✓ fooitório e foofoode; foofoofoofoo e foo foofoo;✓ foo", "foo": "www.foo.com", "foodo": "aa", "foode": "foo", "foofoo": "foo", "foofoonto": "", "fooro": "1", "cep": "foofoo", "foofooo": "Bla, foola fooa"} }'  -qO- http://foo/jspui/foo.jsp
```

How to substitute the **long_json** using *heredoc* inside a shell script file?

Comment: Why do you want to use a here document for that? And how is that related to the last argument?

Comment: if you want to prettify `long_json` can you not just wrap it into a multiline string between the single quotes?

Comment: @HaukeLaging actually I am using lines finishing with '\', but here docs are cleaner.
Maybe I got it all wrong but heredoc seems to put the content only at the end of the command, so how would I insert it at the middle?

Comment: @steeldriver that solved the problem, Thanks

Comment: A here document writes data to the stdin of a command. It does not affect the command line at all. You can use a here document within command substitution and assign the data to a variable, though. That variable can then be used in a command line.

Comment: FWIW if you use `curl` instead, that can handle POST data from stdin, including heredoc. Also `wget` doesn 't have any `-0` (zero) option; it appears you meant `-O-` (cap-oh dash = output to stdout), which is the default for `curl` and doesn't need to be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LONG_JSON=$(cat <<EOT
{
  "foocao": 0,
  "foorio":
  {
    "foo": "foofoofoo",
    "foofooe": "foofoo",
    "foon": "fooe",
    "fool": "foo.com",
    "fooa": "foofoo"
  },
  "fooade":
  {
    "foofoofoo": "foofoo-foo-foo-foo-foofoofoo",
    "foo": "fooTE",
    "fool": "baa.com",
    "foofoo": "foo9-foo",
    "fooao": "foofoo",
    "fooor": "foofoo",
    "foofoo": "foofooia",
    "foofooo": "fooo",
    "foos": "✓ foofooade e foofooe;✓ foofooa, foofooação fooal e Polífoo e foofoo foonil;✓ foofoo e foor;✓ foofoofoo, foofoo e fooa;✓ foofooção e foofooe de fooessão;✓ Saúde;✓ fooura;✓ fooação;✓ fooitório e foofoode; foofoofoofoo e foo foofoo;✓ foo",
    "foo": "www.foo.com",
    "foodo": "aa",
    "foode": "foo",
    "foofoo": "foo",
    "foofoonto": "",
    "fooro": "1",
    "cep": "foofoo",
    "foofooo": "Bla, foola fooa"
  }
}
EOT
)
wget --header='Content-Type:application/json' --post-data="$LONG_JSON" -qO- http://foo/jspui/foo.jsp
```